# solrj Query with child-parent relationsship fails

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I have the following solrj query:

```
    HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr").build();
    solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.set("q", "*:*");
    query.setFilterQueries("rt_tag:[2017-01-20T00:00:00Z TO NOW]","_relationship_:parent");
    query.setFields("[child parentFilter=\"_relationship_:parent\"]","rt_*");       
    QueryResponse response = solr.query("rtm_aggregations_shard1_replica1", query);
    SolrDocumentList docList = response.getResults();
```

When i execute this query, I get the following error:

```
> ERROR SolrDispatchFilter null:java.lang.NullPointerException
> null:java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.apache.solr.response.transform.ChildDocTransformer.transform(ChildDocTransformerFactory.java:137)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.response.BinaryResponseWriter$Resolver.writeResultsBody(BinaryResponseWriter.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.response.BinaryResponseWriter$Resolver.writeResults(BinaryResponseWriter.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.response.BinaryResponseWriter$Resolver.resolve(BinaryResponseWriter.java:88)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeVal(JavaBinCodec.java:158)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeNamedList(JavaBinCodec.java:148)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeKnownType(JavaBinCodec.java:242)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeVal(JavaBinCodec.java:153)
>   at
> org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.marshal(JavaBinCodec.java:96)
```

However, executing the corresponding query per http directly works fine:

```
http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr/rtm_aggregations_shard1_replica1/select?q=*:*&fq=rt_tag:[2017-01-20T00:00:00Z%20TO%20NOW]&fq=_relationship_:parent&fl=[child%20parentFilter=%22_relationship_:parent%22],rt_*
```

Why does it not work with solrj?

Comment: May I ask which version of Solr are you connecting to and which version of Solrj are you using?

Comment: I am using solrj 6.4.0 and solr 4.10.3 (from Cloudera 5.8.3). Can that explain the troubles? Should I downgrade solrj (I cannot upgrad solr)?

Comment: I have added an answer, to explain your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a Solrj 6.4.0 client with Solr 4.10.3.

This versions mix can explain the troubles you're experiencing.

> javabin is a custom binary format used to write out solr's response in
>   a fast and efficient manner.

And in my experience, I recommend to use the same exact version of Solrj.

In Solrj 4.10.3 this is the line to create a client:

```
  HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/");
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @stefan.m the problem still arise even working with version 4.10.4.

After a check looking at [source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/commit/d6003c3ef3e173300ab7d52e12cd0e85fc9ca348), it seems you're facing with a bug.
This is the line 137 of class ChildDocTransformerFactory.java in the version Solr 4.x.

```
@Override
public void transform(SolrDocument doc, int docid) {

  FieldType idFt = idField.getType();
  Object parentIdField = doc.getFirstValue(idField.getName());

  // *** line 137 ***
  String parentIdExt = parentIdField instanceof IndexableField
    ? idFt.toExternal((IndexableField)parentIdField)
    : parentIdField.toString();
```

There are two options here, I mean only `idFt` or `parentIdField` can be `null`.

I would suggest try to add a `fl` parameter to your query adding the parent Id Field.

Comment: Due to some proxy problem I could not download Solrj 4.10.3, but I tested with version 4.10.4. Unfortunately, the behaviour is exactly the same as with Solrj 6.4.0, the same error occurs on the server.

Comment: Very strange. I'll take a look at source code between 4.10.3 and earlier versions.

Comment: I'm not very proficient in SOLR. What do you mean with parent Id field?

Answer (score 0):

The query that is sent to Solr is the following:

```
http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr/rtm_aggregations_shard1_replica1/select?q=*:*&fq=rt_tag:[2017-01-20T00:00:00Z%20TO%20NOW]&fq=_relationship_:parent&fl=[child%20parentFilter=%22_relationship_:parent%22],rt_*&wt=javabin
```

This one also fails, but it will run when removing the part

> &wt=javabin

I don't know the reason for this, but a workaround is to tell solrj to use the XMLResponseParser:

```
solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
```

With this setting, this works fine.